# Why can I not login to a new linux system (amazon linux 2023) from an old one (CentOS 6)

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I try to connect from an old centos 6 system to a "brand new" AWS linux 2023 in ssh and I have an error "**no hostkey alg**".

From the AWS docummentation, on AWS linux 2023, ssh-rsa keys are disabled, but we can authorize them (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/ssh-host-keys-disabled.html), so that is done.

(**dnf install crypto-policies-scripts**)

(**update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY**)

(**reboot**)

But despite of enabling ssh-rsa keys, I still get this annoying "**no hostkey alg**" error.

**ssh-rsa** and **ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com** are listed in server sshd configuration :

```
[user@server ~]# sshd -T | grep "\(ciphers\|macs\|kexalgorithms\|hostkeyalgorithms\|pubkeyacceptedalgorithms\)"

gssapikexalgorithms gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-
ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
macs hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
hostkeyalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
pubkeyacceptedalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

What I cannot understand is on the server sshd logs, there is only two host key types sent to the client, and the offered key type from the client is well listed in the server conf (**ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com**) ?

```
sshd[3161]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Unable to negotiate with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 35848: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,>
```

Here are the complete logs

**Client error message (on the old centos) :**

```
[user@client ~]$ ssh -vvv user@FOOBAR
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for FOOBAR
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/private.key type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/private.key-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 864 bytes for a total of 885
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
no hostkey alg
```

**sshd server logs (the new amazon linux 2023) :**

```
sshd[3161]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
sshd[3161]: debug1: rexec start in 8 out 8 newsock 8 pipe 10 sock 11
sshd[3161]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 5, 5
sshd[3161]: Connection from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 35848 on XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22 rdomain ""
sshd[3161]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
sshd[3161]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
sshd[3161]: debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
sshd[3161]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
sshd[3161]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
sshd[3161]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
sshd[3161]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
sshd[3161]: debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 [preauth]
sshd[3161]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match) [preauth]
sshd[3161]: Unable to negotiate with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 35848: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,>
sshd[3161]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Not programming or development, but: your server doesn't appear to have an RSA key. According to the page you link, AWSLinux by default doesn't generate an RSA key and to do so you must set 'cloud-config', which you don't mention. (To _use_ that RSA key with ssh-rsa _algorithm_, as is needed for your very old OpenSSH 5.3 client, you must _also_ do the crypto-policy change you do mention, which changes the config file as you saw with `sshd -T`.)

Comment: you are perfectly right, server was missing is own rsa key. thanks.